# Django maintaining app specific css in gulp-minify main.css

Tags: css, django, sass, gulp

I am setting up a new development environment that will allow for a single website with multiple apps. I have chosen to use django and setup has proceeded smoothly. I have created a gulpfile that will minify my scss and uglify my js as well as a few other items.

The issue that I have encountered is if each app I create has it's own css file how can I maintain the relationship of that css code to that app inside the now minify css created by my gulp task?

I can see using namespace to help maintain the relationships but what I wish to avoid is having app1 and app2 having a conflict on an `<h2>` for example. Or having app1 now dictating how all `<h2>` are going to render. Is there a way to setup the css or scss to maintain application specific css?

Gulpfile task that minifys

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
return gulp.src('static/scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('static/stylesheets'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('static/stylesheets'))
    .pipe(gzip(gzip_options))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('static/stylesheets'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

Comment: The answer I have arrive to is this question is by using namespace and scss nesting. We will create a `<div>` tag with a class of the app name `<div class="app1">`. All HTML related to the app will be placed inside this tag in all locations in which the relationship needs to be maintained. Example in a django base.html you might have several blocks in which app html could be rendered. Then in my scss folder I will build .scss files with .app1 class and nest all related css/sass within. In this way my gulp task will collect all .scss files and minify them into the compiled main.css.